# Modifying array in JavaScript using array method

Tags: javascript

let fruits = ['apple' , 'cherry', 'grape', undefined, 'lemon'
,'melon'];

i have those array of fruits.
i want to replace undefined with another fruit,
and return all the array with new fruit included.
how to do that using array method in javascript
i do need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `.splice` to replace undefined with new fruit. But just note that it's also possible to achieve it with `.map` and `.filter`

```js
let arr = ['apple' , 'cherry', 'grape', undefined, 'lemon' ,'melon'];
 
let index = arr.indexOf(undefined)
arr.splice(index, 1, 'new fruit')

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method

```js
let fruits = ['apple' , 'cherry', 'grape', undefined, 'lemon' ,'melon'];
fruits.splice(fruits.indexOf(undefined),1,"newFruit")
console.log(fruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of what loops are used for. You can use for, or forEach.

```js
let fruits = ['apple' , 'cherry', 'grape', undefined, 'lemon' ,'melon'];


fruits.forEach((fruit,index) => {
  if(fruit == undefined) {
    fruits[index] = 'Some other fruit'
   }
})

console.log(fruits)
```

Comment: thanks, now i know how to use index parameter for looping in forEach

Answer (score 1):

One of ways we can do this is also by using maps as norbekoff told.
But the result should be stored in a new Array.If you want to do it inplace then you can go with splice method.

```js
let arr = ['apple' , 'cherry', 'grape', undefined, 'lemon' ,'melon'];
 
let newArr=arr.map((ele)=>{
  if(!ele){
      ele="new Fruit";
      }
      return ele;
 });
 
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: thanks, another way to find the undefined